# Articles with job position and names

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Is it necessary to use the definite article while writing an official letter or filling out an application  and addressing the Rector of a university?

e.g.
To (the) Rector of University
First Name/Last name of the Rector

Comment: No, it's not necessary, but it's also not necessarily wrong. There are many different ways of addressing someone that are all acceptable. The specific full title of the person and the name of the university would also help in determining what the phrasing should or could be; it can change depending on context. In broader terms, for instance, names can be put either before or after titles. If the name comes first, it's unlikely you'd use an article with the title.

Comment: Thank you! The exact phrasing would be "to (the) Rector of Tomsk State University" or "to (the) Dean of the Faculty of Foreign Languages"

Comment: If used in that way, the title is not actually used as a title, but a common noun. Just like there is a difference between *President Trump* and *the president of the United States* (not the capitalization). So, in your example, it would be *to **the rector** of Tomsk State University* or *to **the dean** of the Faculty of Foreign Language*.

Comment: Thank you so much! But if the phrase goes "to (the) Rector of Tomsk State University, George Mayer" ?

Comment: No; in *to the rector*, *rector* is not a title but a common noun, so it should be in lowercase. In the analogy I used in my other comment, it would be *to the president of the United States*, not *to the President of the United States*.

Comment: For it to be capitalized, it could be *Rector George Mayer, Tomsk State University*.